# Returning closures from functions — (expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body)

Tags: swift

I've just started learning SwiftUI. I'm wondering if anyone could give me an advice.

I'm struggling to understand why the code bellow have an error but it works if I changed to `print("I'm driving to \($1).")`. What's the problem with using `\($0)` here? It seems there is no problem with `print("I'm cycling \($0) to \($1).")`.

```
import SwiftUI

func createTravelMethod(distance: Int) -> (String, String) -> Void {
    if distance < 5 {
        return {
                print("I'm walking to \($1).")
        }
    } else if distance < 20 {
        return {
            print("I'm cycling \($0) to \($1).")
        }
    } else {
        return {
            print("I'm driving to \($0).")
        }
    }
}
let travelMethod = createTravelMethod(distance: 15)
travelMethod("London", "Paris")
```

Comment: That is a very advanced place to “start learning”. You need to read http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_closures  including http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_function_returning_function. You have promised to return a function that takes two parameters so every one of your `return` statements must mention both parameters. You cannot mention only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import SwiftUI

func createTravelMethod(distance: Int) -> (String, String) -> Void {
    if distance < 5 {
        return {
                print("I'm walking to \($1).")
        }
    } else if distance < 20 {
        return { a, b in
            print("I'm cycling \(a) to \(b).")
        }
    } else {
        return { a, b in
            print("I'm driving to \(a).")
        }
    }
}
let travelMethod = createTravelMethod(distance: 15)
travelMethod("London", "Paris")
```

or this:

```
func createTravelMethod(distance: Int) -> (String, String) -> Void {

    return {
        if distance < 5 {
            print("I'm walking to \($1).")

        } else if distance < 20 {
            print("I'm cycling \($0) to \($1).")
        } else {
            print("I'm driving to \($0).")
        }
    }
}
let travelMethod = createTravelMethod(distance: 15)
travelMethod("London", "Paris")
```